# using let standard function and evaulating the final statment in the let block as null when using the elvis operator

Tags: kotlin

I am playing around with the takeIf and let standard function to mimic the if/else statement.

After some research I have noticed some unexpected behaviour if the final statement in the let block returns null then the elvis will be evaluated as null and call the showError().

But in some cases it works as expected as I have written different implementations below with comments

```
val person: Person? = Person(isAdult = true)
```

Works as expected

```
if(person != null && person.isAdult) {
    showPerson(person)
}
else {
    showError()
}
```

Question? This will call showPerson and then showError as ::ShowPerson will return null at the last statement

```
person?.takeIf { it.isAdult }
    ?.let { ::showPerson }
    ?: run { showError() }
```

Question? This will show the error

```
person?.takeIf { it.isAdult }
    ?.let(::showPerson)
    ?: showError()
```

Works as expected

```
if(person != null && person.isAdult) {
    showPerson(person)
    hideProgressWithSuccess()
}
else {
    showError()
    hideProgress()
}
```

Question? This will showPerson then hideProgressWithSuccess as the hideProgressWithSuccess is the final statement and returns nothing. I guess this works as expected as the final statement doesn't return null

```
person?.takeIf { it.isAdult }
    ?.let { it: Person ->
        showPerson(it)
        hideProgressWithSuccess()
    }
    ?: run {
        showError()
        hideProgress()
    }


class Person(val isAdult: Boolean = true)
```

Explicitly returning null to test this scenerio

```
fun showPerson(person: Person): String? {
    println(person)
    return null
}

fun showError() {
    println("Person Error")
}

fun hideProgressWithSuccess() {}

fun hideProgress() {}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find out what the unexpected behavior is from the examples.

Comment: `hideProgressWithSuccess` cannot return [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), it returns [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) which is a valid non-null value.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you're expecting that's not happening, because what you described above behaves exactly how I'd expect it to. You've provided a good illustration of why chaining an Elvis after a `let` statement can be error prone and poor for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a traditional "if condition then action1 else action2" statement the execution of action2 depends only on the condition, never on anything you might do in action1, and only one of action1 or action2 is executed.

Yes, the `let` function returns the result of the expression, and the result may be null or false. So if you use the elvis operator after it, you will not get the strict "if..then..else" semantic.

You can still get the "if" semantic if you use either the `also` or the `apply` function instead of `let`. These functions just return the object itself, no matter what you do inside them. So we can be sure that they return something, and that the else-part of the elvis operator is not executed.

You can see an overview of the different scope-functions in this [table](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#function-selection), it helps you to decide which function to use, depending what you want them to return, and if you want to use "it" ot "this" inside them.